# Cannot start because of volume group issue

Tags: boot, partitioning, swap, hibernate

I'm not sure if this was caused by hibernate, or a system update, or a combination.

I cannot start anything graphical on my ThinkPad X1 Carbon anymore.

I can start in text mode, if I stop the Lenovo start screen with Enter.

The errors I get just before the disk encryption key prompt are (I'm typing this manually, I only have pictures):

```
[ time ] pci 0000:00:07.0: DPC: RP PIO log size 0 is invalid
[ time ] pci 0000:00:07.2: DPC: RP PIO log size 0 is invalid
/scripts/init-premount/plymouth: line 36: /sbin/plymouthd: not found
/scripts/init-premount/plymouth: line 37: /bin/plymouth: not found
  Volume group "vgubuntu" not found
  Cannot process volume group vg
  Volume group "vgubuntu" not found
  Cannot process volume group vgubuntu
Please unlock disk nvme0n1p3_crypt:
```

Another weird behavior, is that my little USB-C dock gives me this messages every 4 seconds, until I disconnect it:

```
[ time ] usb usb2-port3: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
```

---

What I've tried so far:

I've tried adding `noresume` to the Linux start command.

I've tried removing `splash` from the Linux start command. It removes one of the "Volume group" error messages, and the plymouth errors. The rest is the same.

There is no `vgubuntu` in `/dev/mapper`. There is only `vgubuntu-root`, another one related to `swap`, and a third.

I've tried to run `update-initramfs -uk all`, with the `RESUME` variable set to one of the  other files in `/dev/mapper/`, not that I had much hope...

I'm not surprised that hibernate failed, I don't think my swap partition is large enough for it (16 GB RAM, 8 GB swap). I'm a little surprised hibernate was attempted at all, in these conditions.

I think the PCI thing might be unrelated, and that it's an incompatibility issue between versions of the kernel and... something else. At the same time, PCI failing might explain the USB behavior.

Any clue? Can I force the start to skip resume, besides adding `noresume` to the command? What is even this volume group that seems to be missing?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue as yours. As my investigation, it's due to plymouth([see more](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Plymouth)) crash during startup. Just try to fix the plymouth. My solution is installing xubuntu-desktop. Command below:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install xubuntu-desktop
```